# Making interactable computer screen in game Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I need to do a interactable computer screen in Unity 3D for my game like Streamer's Life Simulator or Internet Cafe Simulator.I used Canvas and tried TextureRenderer but didn't work as well.What systems I should work on for this?

When I tried to use canvas for this it was reversing the text (in attached photo)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your canvas is pointing the wrong side you can rotate the canvas.

On the `Rect Transform` component rotate the `y` axis by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a plain and try to apply render texture to plain material. It will give the proper output.

You can use this sample code:

```
texture = new Texture2D(count_x, count_y, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
 
Rect rectReadPicture = new Rect(0, 0, count_x, count_y);
 
RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
 
// Read pixels
texture.ReadPixels(rectReadPicture, 0, 0);
texture.Apply();
 
RenderTexture.active = null;
```